# Rewrite rule is not effecting the site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, conditional-statements

I am trying to write rules in .htaccess file.

I Wrote the rule like this:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)&dgid=([0-9]+)$
 RewriteRule destination_content-id-(.*)-dgid-(.*)\.htm$ destination_content.html?id=$1&dgid=$2 [L]
```

restarted the server.

Before it is having the following rule.

```
 RewriteEngine on
        # Parse out basename, but remember the fact.
        RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$              $1       [C,E=WasHTML:yes]
        # Rewrite to document.phtml if exists...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.phtml -f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$                    $1.phtml [S=1]
        # ...else reverse the previous basename cutout.
        RewriteCond %{ENV:WasHTML}            ^yes$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$                    $1.html
```

it works fine.

but my rule not working.

Could you please help me in solving the issue.

Thanks,
Srilu

Comment: What are you trying to do with your rewrite rule?

Comment: Seems strange, you ask for a xxx-<id>-yyy-<gid>-zzz to be rewriten to content.html?id=<id>&gid=<gid> only when the URL already have a QueryString of the same format? Did you tried removing the RewriteCond? It does not seem to belong here. But maybe you can detail a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Leave out the RewriteCond (It does not match the RewriteRule).

You'll just need the RewriteRule and I guess you want it to look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule destination_content-id-([0-9]+)-dgid-([0-9]+)\.htm$ destination_content.html?id=$1&dgid=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Yes, But it is not working. Could you please help me in solving the issue?

Comment: What does your URL look like? And what do you want to rewrite it to?